# How load into Hadoop/Hive only the 365 more recent files?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql, hadoop2

I create a table:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE events (
  id bigint, received_at string, generated_at string, source_id int, source_name string, source_ip string, facility string, severity string, program string, message string
)
PARTITIONED BY (
  dt string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3://mybucket/folder1/folder2';
```

Inside s3://mybucket/folder1/folder2 there are multiple folders, in the naming format `dt=YYYY-MM-DD/` and inside each folder, 1 file, in the naming format `YYYY-MM-DD.tsv.gz`

I then load the table via `MSCK REPAIR TABLE events;`. When I do a `SELECT * FROM events LIMIT 5;`, I get

```
OK
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The operation is not valid for the object's storage class (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidObjectState; Request ID: 66C6392F74DBED77), S3 Extended Request ID: YPL1P4BO...+fxF+Me//cp7Fxpiuqxds2ven9/4DEc211JI2Q7BLkc=
Time taken: 0.823 seconds
```

Because objects older than 365 days have been moved to Glacier.

**How do I programmatically load into the able only the 365 more recent files, or better, I can specify load only files newer than/named past a set date?**

*PS: I'm only going to fire up a Hadoop/Hive cluster when needed. It will always start from scratch - no previous data in it - hence the concern being only with adding data, not removing it.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to avoid Hive from seeing the Glacier-backed partitions by only specifically adding the S3-backed partitions. You would need to do this for each of the 365 dates after you have created the table, like so:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ...;
ALTER TABLE events ADD PARTITION (dt = '2015-01-01');
ALTER TABLE events ADD PARTITION (dt = '2015-01-02');
ALTER TABLE events ADD PARTITION (dt = '2015-01-03');
...
ALTER TABLE events ADD PARTITION (dt = '2015-12-31');
SELECT * FROM events LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: I'm only going to fire up a Hadoop/Hive cluster when needed. So it will always start from scratch - no previous data in it - hence the concern being only with adding data, not removing it.

Comment: Maybe I can then script the `ADD PARTITION` statements? One by one would be a nightmare.

Comment: Yeah that should be easily scriptable.

Comment: That would be a better answer.

Comment: How to script a bunch of date-driven commands is probably a different question and depends on your platform, tools, etc. This answer is just sticking to how to invoke Hive to not read from Glacier subdirectories.

Comment: It's an Amazon Hadoop/Hive cluster with the default settings. There has got to be a better way to do this. I modified the question to specify "programmatically load" Thanks.

Comment: A bash script would work. Would using `LOCATION` or creating a view with the necessary data be a better option?